# PHP script not automatically updating when moved to another server

Tags: php

A friend built a ranking system on his site and I am trying to host in on mine via WordPress and Go Daddy. It updates for him but when I load it to my site, it works for 6 hours, but as soon as the reload is supposed to occur, it errors and I get a 500 timeout error.

His page is at: jeremynoeljohnson .com/yakezieclub

My page is currently at http://sweatingthebigstuff.com/yakezieclub but when you `?reload=1` it will give the error.

Any idea why this might be happening? Any settings that I might need to change?

Here is the top of the index.php file. I'm not sure which part of any of it is messing up. I literally uploaded the same code as him.

Here's the reload part:

```
$cachefile = "rankings.html";
$daycachefile = "rankings_history.xml";
$cachetime = (60 * 60) * 6; // every 6 hours, the cache refreshes
$daycachetime = (60 * 60) * 24; 
         // every 24 hours, the history will be written to 
         // - or whenever the page is requested after 24 hours has passed
$writenewdata = false;

if (!empty($_GET['reload']))
{
    if ($_GET['reload']== 1)
    {
        $cachetime = 1;
    }
}

if (!empty($_GET['reloadhistory']))
{
    if ($_GET['reloadhistory'] == 1)
    {
        $daycachetime = 1;
        $cachetime = 1;
    }
}

if (file_exists($daycachefile) && 
                       (time() - $daycachetime < filemtime($daycachefile)))
{
    // Do nothing
}
else
{
    $writenewdata = true;
    $cachetime = 1;
}

// Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
if (file_exists($cachefile) && (time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)))
{
    include($cachefile);
    echo "<!-- Cached ".date('jS F Y H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->";
    exit;
}
ob_start(); // start the output buffer

?>
```

Comment: This belongs on stackoverflow.

Comment: how do i get people to answer it there?

Comment: Your question will be moved there, follow the link that comes up when it does. You may need to link your accounts when it's moved to claim back as the OP. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association

Comment: Does the web service have write access to the directory it would save the cache file to?

Comment: Try to use absolute path for all used files.

Answer (score 2):

I would check the permissions and path for the cache file as well as absolute paths to all the files

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php